# How do i correctly use angular $timeout service outside of a typescript constructor?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly use the angular $timeout service with TypeScript - So that i can show a splash-screen-like-behavior when someone for example clicks on a "Log In"-button.

```
interface INavigationController {
        username: string;
        password: string;
        loggedIn: boolean;
        ready: boolean;
        signIn(): void;
        signOut(): void;
    }

    class NavigationController implements INavigationController {
        username: string;
        password: string;
        loggedIn: boolean;
        ready: boolean;

        static $inject = ['$timeout'];
        constructor(private $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
            var vm = this;
            vm.username = this.username;
            vm.password = this.password;
            vm.ready = true;

            // The line below work just fine from within here - but i want the behavior
            // when someone clicks a button, not directly like this.
            // Remove vm.ready = true above, before...
            //$timeout(function () { vm.ready = true;}, 2200);}

        signIn() {
            if (!this.username || !this.password) {
                alert("You need to frickin enter som details, man!");
            } else {
                this.ready = false;
                this.$timeout(function () {
                    this.ready = true;
                }, 2200);
            }
        }
```

I have also tried to set the `invokeApply?:boolean` to true:

```
this.$timeout(function () {
    this.ready = true;
}, 2200, true);
```

- Without any success...

If i `console.log(this.ready);` from within the `this.$timeout(function()...` it will show me `true` after 2200ms, but it seems that the `$apply()` doesn't apply?

Would appreciate if someone could enlighten me in how to use the $timeout and other services like it, correctly - Preferably using the style-guide i'm aiming for i.e. using "controllerAs with vm" - [John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#controllers)

Comment: You might find this video enlightening : https://youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: @basarat - Thank you, i did find it enlightening. Been watching a couple of your videos before (unfortunately not the one you pointed me to) previously, and i hope you keep making more! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
this.$timeout(()=> {
                this.ready = true;
            }, 2200);
```

if you use function(){} pattern you don't have access to `this` (`this` is not the one you expect)

Comment: Awesome! Great stuff. I should remember to use this lambda syntax for methods outside of my constructor at least. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The 'this' inside the timeout is the this of the timeout function. You need to define a variable outside to reference that scope (usually called 'that') and refer to it inside the timeout:

```
var that = this;
$timeout(function() {
     that.value ='eggs';
}, 2200);
```

Comment: please don't memorize `this` when using `TypeScript`. `TypeScript` is all about 'magic' with `this`!

Answer (score 1):

try this, mate

```
var obj = this;
this.$timeout(function () {
  obj.ready = true;
  }, 2200);
```